# 64bit OS for Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, 64-bit

I have a Raspbery Pi 3 and I am looking to use the 64-bit processor (if possible) that comes with it.

My question is - are there any 64-bit operating systems currently available for the Pi 3?  I see that `Raspbian Jessie` was last updated in on 27th May - but there is no mention of 64-bit functionality.

I've tried Googling to discover the answer here, but I am having little success with this method.

Comment: Yes there is no 64-bit Jessie. Just for my information, what do you think that having a 64-bit OS will enable you to do that you can't now?

Comment: I have a programme, that was developed for a 64-bit OS.  It won't run properly on Jessie as it stands.

Comment: OK, but Pi only has 1G RAM, i.e. much less than the 32-bit addressing limit. Why would 64 bits make any difference on a Pi?

Comment: Honestly, I thought it wouldn't, but when I Googled the errors I was getting, it said the usually appear after executing a 64-bit built programme on a 32-bit OS.  So I was just following that.

Comment: MongoDB databases are limited to 2G in size in 32-bit architectures, and the 32-bit releases will soon be deprecated. From the manual: _Starting in MongoDB 3.2, 32-bit binaries are deprecated and will be unavailable in future releases_. Just discovered this, so a 64 bit Linux distro for the Pi would be welcome here as well.

Comment: You really want to run MongoDB on a RPi? Good luck, but with only 1 GB of total RAM you can just play around, nothing much you can do with MongoDB on such hardware. People tend to forget that even RPi can do many tasks, it is not an exchange for a full blown server such as MongoDB dedicated production-ready server setup with 64GB+ of RAM and 8 CPU's.

Comment: Also see [Supported 64bit hardware](https://lists.centos.org/pipermail/arm-dev/2016-September/002270.html) on the CentOS ARM-dev mailing list. It provides a list of better ARMv8 hardware that you have with RPI3. BTW, I own all four devices for testing, and I have access to one ARMv8 server. Of them all, the RPI3 is the worse. I recommend the Pine64 or HiKey. Both are ARMv8, both have CRC+Crypto extensions (RPI3 and ODROID lack them), and all of thm use 64-bit OS except for RPI3.

Answer (score 5):

You can now get [SUSE Linux Enterprise Server for the Raspberry Pi](https://www.suse.com/eval/download?event_id=DGSLE12SP2&event_name=Eval:+SLES+Raspberry+Pi&icid=GSDGNEval23017&icname=Eval:+SLES+Raspberry+Pi+Nurture&build=ccUe-rz974A~&login_required=1), which is a 64bit OS. There is also documentation [here](https://www.suse.com/documentation/suse-best-practices/sles-rpi-quick/data/sles-rpi-quick.html).

There is also openSUSE Leap (SUSE Linux Enterprise is based on this one) and Tumbleweed (rolling distribution) available [here](https://en.opensuse.org/HCL:Raspberry_Pi3). Both are 64bit.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are several 64bit Linux' out there for Pi3, Arch Linux for example.

The reason you'd want to use a 64bit OS on ARM has nothing to do with DRAM addressing (32bit Arm7a has address extensions that allow 1 TeraByte). The AARM64 architecture has numerous advantages over AARCH32; full DP floating point in hardware, a deeper SIMD/NEON vector, more registers. It's about twice as fast in dp-floatng point tests, faster yet for crypto.  64bit likely uses marginally more DRAM to execute.

Comment: Looking into Arch Linux, their install page seems to hint that it won't be a 64-bit operating system: https://archlinuxarm.org/platforms/armv8/broadcom/raspberry-pi-3

Comment: @DustinCook As of commenting, there is!

Comment: 32bit addressing doesn't allow mmap:ing multiple >1G files. I ran into this with (admittedly not really well setup) influxdb instance. Running 64bit kernel with 32bit userspace and then 64bit systemd-nspawn in that solved this issue.

Comment: Pasi - Yes, each address space is limited to 32bit addressing (4GB) on a 32bit OS.

Answer (score 1):

You can now get a 64Bit version of Windows 10 IoT Core for the Raspberry Pi. Its been labelled as Windows 10 IoT Core **Pro**.

Use the below link to find a distributor: https://www.windowsforiotdevices.com/